# Bootstrap - Columns appear on top of each other

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, tomcat, frontend

I'm new to Bootstrap but i'm really confused here. I started new Maven Web Project and wanted to put Bootstrap into jsp file, but after running page on Tomcat columns appear on top of each other when they're supposed to be inline. What am I doing wrong?

```
    <%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" session="false"%>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">



    <title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
     <h1>Hello World!</h1>
      <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
  </div>
</div>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this works for you?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Slico/4amyjL4j/1/)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
```

You can ignore the code above just a copy&paste

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: That's the output that I have, columns should be inline but they are in row

Comment: Is working as intended. Check the new JSFiddle and check the difference. Let me know if it helps you

Comment: in JSF Fiddle everything looks fine but when I put it in my project columns are the same size no matter how I resize browser window. My imports seems fine but it looks like Tomcat doesn't see Bootstrap css

Comment: I mean the browser console. I think the problem is the link to the bootstrap files. Can you try the link with bootstrap cdn? i updated my answer to include them.

Comment: Yeah, that was the case. I don't know why my links were not working but maxcdn are fine. Thank you.

Comment: You can have the bootstrap files on your website directory the only error then is the link to them. Mark as correct if usefull:)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have defined a wrong path location for bootstrap. This means the browser receives an HTTP 404 when it requests bootstrap files. You should have the name of the project/application before the path to your css. If you don't have the project name, Tomcat will direct the request to the ROOT folder. This is how bootstrap link should be:

```
 <link href="/project/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Also, you can dynamically get your project name, or the context path, using this code below:

```
<link href="/${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

A side suggestion... since you are using Maven, why don't you use [WebJars](http://www.webjars.org/)? It is really powerful and well documented.